# AndroidのCheckBoxPreference項目を動的に非表示にしたい

Tags: android

AndroidのPreference項目を動的に非表示にしたいです。

```
<PreferenceScreen>
・・・
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="test_key"
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:title="@string/test_title" />
・・・
</PreferenceScreen>
```

上記の項目を
コード上で非表示にしたいです。

```
CheckBoxPreference test = getCheckBoxPrefInstance("test_key");
if (test != null) {
    test.setSelectable(false);(1)
//    test.setEnabled(false);(2)
}
```

(1)の場合は、活性のような表示ですが、タップができない状態
(2)の場合は、非活性のような表示となっています。

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/customize-your-settings?hl=ja

```
EditTextPreference signaturePreference = findPreference("signature");
if (signaturePreference != null) {
    signaturePreference.setVisible(true);
}
```

上記のような記載があり、EditTextPreferenceですが、上記を見ますと「setVisible」を使用すれば良さそうなのですが、

```
if (test != null) {
//    test.setSelectable(false);(1)
//    test.setEnabled(false);(2)
    test.setVisible(false);(3)
}
```

(3)とすると、setVisibleはCheckBoxPreferenceに見つからないと怒られてしまいます。
チェックボックス項目を非表示にする方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: AndroidXの[CheckBoxPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/CheckBoxPreference)は`isVisible`を実装しているようで、ご覧のドキュメントもそれのドキュメントのようです。 参考: [AndroidX への移行  |  Android デベロッパー  |  Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

公式リファレンス [CheckBoxPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/CheckBoxPreference#inherited-methods) に `setVisible(boolean visible)` は明記されています。

> setVisibleはCheckBoxPreferenceに見つからないと怒られてしまい

というのは、CheckBoxPreference という代物が `setVisible` というメソッドが使えないわけではなく、原因は全く別のところにある、*使えるはずのものが使えなくなっている*、と考えた方がいいでしょう。

おそらく、`import` が適切にできていないのではないでしょうか。

`buile.gradle (:app)`

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0' // Java
```

または

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.0' // Kotlin Java 兼用
```

そして import 文

```
import androidx.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
```

android**X** のものがちゃんと選択されているかどうか、確かめてください。

Fragment:

```
public class MySettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
        CheckBoxPreference check = findPreference("check");
        check.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

preferences.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <CheckBoxPreference app:key="check" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

こんな感じで何の問題もなく `setVisible` できています。

Comment: おっしゃる通りでした。もともと「import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;」をインポートしていました。設定項目の非活性、活性があるから非表示、表示もできるよね、と思い見ていたサイト自体もandroidxのサイトとは気づいておりませんでした。